# Image in one column is expanding to the second column

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have defined a grid with some rows and two columns
In [0,0] I have placed an image with main attributes as below:

```
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
 Stretch="None" Margin="10 0 0 0" Width="260"
```

And in [0,1] I have placed a label with some text in it with some main attributes like this:

```
 HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="36" FontSize="16"
```

My question is why if I remove the `width = 260` from image field then suddenly also the label in next column is disappearing? I think the image expands and covers it. But why? Shouldn't it be limited to its own [0,0] cell?

Comment: And also my ColumnDefintions are both set to "Width = Auto"

Comment: Why are you specifying the width of the image to 260 ?? is it important ? is it the width of the image itself ??

Comment: Auto means size to the requirements of the content.

Comment: Try to make the attribute "ShowGridLines" to true, in your Grid definition line, it will help you to see if the second collumn is acrossed or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns are autosizing to the *size of their contents*, so I would guess that your image in (0,0) isn't actually spreading into column 1 it is just that column 0 is growing so large that you can't see column 1 anymore.

If you make the column size * you will constrain it to the available space. As someone else said, you can use ShowGridLines to help debug what is going on with your columns, especially if you add a second row just to see where the division between your columns is.